Latest update blows the dock away after wake from sleep
After today's update, not even dash to dock works.  I put the system to sleep, I wake it, and sure enough, no dock.  The Extension is reset to OFF every time I put the system to sleep.  This is extremely irritating because this bug occurs over and over with different updates and the fix is different each time.  Ubuntu doesn't seem to want anyone to be able to see the dock constantly and they do everything to hide it.  
See the extensions here:

Everytime I resume/wake the system up, Dash to Dock is turned off.  In this image, I've turned it back on.  Same thing happens if I have Ubuntu Dock turned on. How do I get the dock to stay put permanently and resistant to Ubuntu update mutations?

I'm now using Dash to Panel.  The dock survives suspend-resume.  I hope Ubuntu developers stop messing with the dock. Leave it alone.
